# Any good (free) text-to-speech engines out there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text-to-speech, twilio

I've been scouring the SO board and google and can't find any really good recommendations for this. I'm building a Twilio application and the text-to-speech (TTS) engine is way bad. Plus, it's a pain in the ass to test since I have to deploy every time. Is there a significantly better resource out there that could render to a WAV or MP3 file so I can save and use that instead? Maybe there's a great API for this somewhere. I just want to avoid recording 200 MP3 files myself, would rather have this generated programatically...

Things I've seen and rejected:

- http://www.yakitome.com/ (I couldn't force myself to give them my email)
- http://www2.research.att.com/~ttsweb/tts/demo.php
- http://www.naturalreaders.com/index.htm
- http://www.panopreter.com/index.php (on the basis of crappy website)

Thinking of paying for this, but not sure yet: https://ondemand.neospeech.com/

Obviously I'm new to this, if I'm missing something obvious, please point it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you have access to a mac computer or not. Mac has pretty advanced tts built into the operating system. Apple spent a lot of money on top engineers to research it. It can easily be controlled and even automated from the command prompt. It also has quite a few built in voices to choose from. That is what I used on a recent phone system I put up. But I realize that this is not an option if you don't have a mac.

Another one you might want to check into is http://cepstral.com/ they have very realistic voices. I think they used to be open source but they are no longer and now you need to pay licensing fees. They are very commonly used for high end commercial applications. And are not so much geared towards the home user that wants their article read to them.

Comment: I'm sure I can find a Mac to use - as a PC guy, I'm not used to anyone making my life easier. Thanks for the tip on Cepstral, they have an interesting API through a related company. Will do some research...

Answer (score 0):

I like the YAKiToMe! website the best. It's free and the voices are top quality. In case you're still worried about giving them your email, they've never spammed me in many years of use and I never got onto any spam lists after signing up with them, so I doubt they sold my email. Anyway, the service is great and has lots of features for turning electronic text into audio files in different languages.

As for the API you're looking for,  YAKiToMe! has a well-documented API and it's free to use. You have to register with the site to use it, but that's because it lets you customize pronunciation and voice selection, so it needs to differentiate you from other users.